# Show that there is a set $A$ of Lebesgue measure $0$ such that $A$ is not meager

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, set-theory

The definition of meager set is in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set, I want to show that there is a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ such that it isn't a meager set, I check this answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43478/is-there-a-measure-zero-set-which-isnt-meagre, in Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen's answer he gave an example, but I don't know why the set he gave is not meager, can anyone help me?

Comment: The complement of $V$ might be considered weirder still: a set of full measure (infinity and intersects every set of positive measure, so dense too) that is a countable union of nowhere dense sets (meagre). $V$ is "just" a measure $0$ generic set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The question of finding a non-meager null set has been asked here before if memory serves; however, since this question asks about the details of a **specific construction**, I don't think it constitutes a duplicate.*

---

Each $V_n$ is a union of open sets, hence each $V_n$ is open. Moreover, for each $n$ each rational appears in (at least) one of the components of $V_n$, so each $V_n$ is dense.

$V$ is therefore a **countable intersection of dense open sets**, hence comeager: the complement of a countable *intersection* of *dense open* sets is a countable *union* of *nowhere dense* sets. By the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), no set is both meager and comeager, so $V$ is not meager.